# Get attribute from HTML element that is a json value using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following json returned from service:

```
{
"html": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQpUOimNvXA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}
```

How can I get `src` attribute value i.e. `https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQpUOimNvXA?feature=oembed` using javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from the `iframe` and obtain the `src` attribute:

```js
var jsonString = {"html": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQpUOimNvXA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"}
var src = $(jsonString.html).attr("src");
$("#source").html(src);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cf5e2y89/1/)

```
var data = {
"html": "<iframe width=\"480\" height=\"270\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQpUOimNvXA?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
}

console.log(data.html);

var str = data.html;
var word = str.split(" ");
var word1 = word[3].split('"');
console.log(word1[1]);
```

I made split a couple of times i ended up with `https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQpUOimNvXA?feature=oembed`

Comment: yeah i know KAD has a better answer accept his @Mark